# How to show template name in rendering variant?

Tags: sxa, presentation, templates

I have a template and i want to show the template name in the rendering variant.

I have tried to add a "field" type to the variant, and set its name to "template", but that didn't work.

I have tried using a "token" and set it to $currenttemplate but that didn't work.

Please help me because I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `VariantTemplate` field

[image]

Result:

[image]